# Manual slider should not be visible on transparent areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've bumped into something that will most definetly be a challenge to some of you. At least it is for me and I'm hoping that someone could help me with this.

I'm using 2 images that lay on top of eachother. Then there's a divider image that you control with your cursor to slide over it from left to right, and the other way around.

```
<div class="green_block"></div>
<div class="triforce">
  <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
```

This all works, but I want the divider to not be visible when it touches a transparent area of the top image.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6ubb/2/)

In the case of the fiddle, the blue bar must be shown on top of the Triforce, but not on it's transparent parts. Is this even possible?

Comment: It's possible but not easy. You can create a version of the triforce that is all blue, and only display the part you want. And if you want to automate the process you need the canvas, in order to get the pixels that are transparent. It would be very hard because of browser compatibility, unless really necessary I would look for another way.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer. CSS3 happens to have this -webkit-mask attribute, but that only works in Webkit browsers.

Comment: Well it can certainly be done, but unless it is really needed try to look for an easier way, this would take long to do right

Comment: Does it need to be done? Yes. Do I want to spent weeks on it? No way. I'm open for alternatives, if there are any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that works for me. I created another image where I take the background of the website as the transparent part. I placed this on top of the others and let the divider slide behind it.

Crude solution, not recommendable but in this case it will be sufficient. Thanks for all the help tho. I've learned quite a lot from it.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible using canvas element.
Get pixel data of image using `getImageData` method of canvas and check rgb value. To use `getImageData` you need to put your script file and image on same domain because of cross domain issue.  In this case, the divider is not to be visible on  #00ff00.

[Sample](http://edwardrockhands.com/test/triforce.html)

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image=document.createElement("img");
    image.onload=function(){
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        ctx.fillStyle="#00ff00";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.width);
        ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
        init();
    }

    image.src="Triforce.png";

    function init(){
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
        var data = imageData.data;
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
            var x = mousePos.x;
            var y = mousePos.y;

            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

            ctx.fillStyle="#00ff00";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.width);

            ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

            ctx.fillRect(x, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);

            ctx.fillStyle="#0000ff";
            for(var i=x;i<x+10;i++){
                for(var j=0;j<image.height;j++){
                    var red = data[((image.width * j) + i) * 4];
                    var green = data[((image.width * j) + i) * 4 + 1];
                    var blue = data[((image.width * j) + i) * 4 + 2];
                    var alpha = data[((image.width * j) + i) * 4 + 3];
                    if(!(red==0 && green==255 && blue==0)){
                        ctx.fillRect(i,j,1,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, false);
    }

    function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
            y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Amazing, but sadly this won't work in IE8. And we still have to serve users with IE8 :(

Answer (score 0):

I would use a second image which is exactly the inverse of your image (transparent part=>blue/ colored => transparent).

After i would move two div at the same time at the top image.
the green one and a second which will be (overflow hided) by the divider(the divider should be transparent).

The one (overflow hided) must perform an animation will the divider is moving, so it will look like the exact antagonist of your image

```
  <div class="green_block"></div>
   <div class="triforce">
    <div class="divider">
      <div class="antagonist-div">
      <!-- this one should move inside the divider while he is moving --> 
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I would love to see a Fiddle of this